# LinqPad "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error

Tags: linqpad

I got the error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when run the follow linq query at LinqPad V4.42.14(AnyCPU), database is Oracle 11g.

If I replace

```
where coof.CoofCode == tod.PatTrnsplntFail.CoofCode && coof.OrgCode == prod.OrgCode
```

to

```
where coof.CoofCode == tod.PatTrnsplntFail.CoofCode
```

it works, but I can not remove that factor.

Any body can help me out will be great appreciate.

```
void Main()
{
    var q = (from pat in Pats
            from patr in pat.PatRegisters
            from prod in patr.PatRegisterOrgDets
            from tod in prod.TransplantOrgDets
            select new {
                PatId = pat.PatID,
                FullName = pat.FirstName + ", " + pat.LastName,
                RegisterDate = patr.RegDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                TransplantDate = tod.Transplant.TransplantDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                OrganSpec = tod.OrgSpec.Descrip,
                IsTransplantedFailed = tod.PatTrnsplntFail.TodID == 0 ? false: true,
                TransplantedFailReason = from coof in CausesOfOrgFail
                                         where coof.CoofCode == tod.PatTrnsplntFail.CoofCode && coof.OrgCode == prod.OrgCode
                                         select coof.Descrip
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.PatId);

    q.Dump(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around way to avoid the issue, but acturally I do not think this is a good way, I fell the LinqPad Oracle Driver has internal bugs cause that issue. Joeseph if you could read this, please give your suggestion. So use the follow linq query instead:

```
void Main()
{
    var q1 = (from pat in Pats
            from patr in pat.PatRegisters
            from prod in patr.PatRegisterOrgDets
            from tod in prod.TransplantOrgDets
            where tod.PatTrnsplntFail.TodID == null
            select new {
                PatId = pat.PatID,
                FullName = pat.FirstName + ", " + pat.LastName,
                RegisterDate = patr.RegDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                TransplantDate = tod.Transplant.TransplantDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                OrganSpec = tod.OrgSpec.Descrip,
                IsTransplantedFailed = false,
                CausesOfOrgFailReason = ""
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.PatId);

    var q2 = (from pat in Pats
            from patr in pat.PatRegisters
            from prod in patr.PatRegisterOrgDets
            from tod in prod.TransplantOrgDets
            from coof in CausesOfOrgFail where coof.CoofCode == tod.PatTrnsplntFail.CoofCode && coof.OrgCode == prod.OrgCode
            where tod.PatTrnsplntFail.TodID != null
            select new {
                PatId = pat.PatID,
                FullName = pat.FirstName + ", " + pat.LastName,
                RegisterDate = patr.RegDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                TransplantDate = tod.Transplant.TransplantDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd"),
                OrganSpec = tod.OrgSpec.Descrip,
                IsTransplantedFailed = true,
                CausesOfOrgFailReason = coof.Descrip
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.PatId);

    q1.ToList().Union(q2.ToList()).OrderBy(o => o.PatId).Dump(true);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's linqPad's fault, I get the same error using Entity Framework 5 and Oracle.  I'm using the Oracle ODP.NET files... Running against MSSQL does not produce the problem.